# how do i check if some input are not empty before send to server

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

what is the best way to ckeck if an input is empty or not before sending data to the server

the send button is under bill and i want to check if the 2. input under where is empty or not

http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/V8aSD/2/

```
<h3>
    <span>Selected: </span>
    <span data-bind="text: selectedSection().name" />
</h3>
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: sections">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isSelected }">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedSection">
                <span data-bind="text: name" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate }"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="jsonData2send" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></div>
<script id="when" type="text/html">
    <div>One content</div>
</script>

<script id="what" type="text/html">
    <div>Two content</div>
</script>

<script id="where" type="text/html">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" placeholder="Name"/>
    <input data-bind="value: lastName" placeholder="Nachname"/>
</script>

<script id="bill" type="text/html">
    <form data-bind="submit: sendDataToServer">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</script>
```

Comment: why not use a KnockoutJS validation plugin [example](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the form submit handler in the view-model and test the appropriate value, e.g:

```
self.sendDataToServer = function() {
    if(!self.lastName()) {
        alert('Last name not set!');
        //by default, submit is not sent
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that Knockout prevents the default browser submit action unless you return `true` from the submit handler.

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html for reference